# What's the purpose of using the suffix "if" statement in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I know Ruby supports a suffix `if` like:

```
number = -42 if opposite
```

but what's the purpose of this? Why would it be used in place of the prefix `if` statement?

Comment: I think this form of 'clever' assignment is ugly, but it makes in other cases: `raise some_exception if something_bad`.

Comment: Ruby has it because Perl has it, Perl has it because (AFAIK) sometimes it reads better.

Comment: @user2864740, I agree with you completely. I recall reading the line, “All's well if all ends well.”, and thinking how much better it would have been as  "If all ends well, all's well.”

Answer (score 6):

The suffix-style `if` and `unless` can also be good for "guard clauses", in the form of:

```
return if ...
return unless ...
```

Here's an example:

```
# suffix-style
def save
  return false if invalid?
  # go for it
  true
end
```

Versus:

```
# indented style
def save
  if valid?
    # go for it
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

In the second example, the entire implementation of the method has to be shifted over by one indent due to the `valid?` check, and we need an extra `else` clause. With the suffix style, the `invalid?` check is considered an edge case that we handle and then bail out, and the rest of the method doesn't need an indent or an `else` clause.

This is sometimes called a "guard clause" and is [recommended](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#no-nested-conditionals) by the Ruby Style Guide.

Comment: @vgoff I've edited my answer to make it clear that the example code should return different values for the valid and invalid code paths.

Answer (score 4):

It can make the code easier to read in some cases. I find this to be true especially in the case of `unless`, where you have some action you *usually* want to perform:

```
number = -42 unless some_unusual_circumstance_holds
```

Once you have it for `unless`, for symmetry it makes sense to support it for `if` as well.

Comment: I don't understand why you mention `if` only indirectly. If you have `unless` for things you usually want to support, then you have `if` for things you exceptionally want to support.

Answer (score 3):

```
number = -42 if opposite
```

is the same as

```
if opposite
  number = -42 
end
```

Some people prefer the one-liner for readability reasons. Imagine a line like:

```
process_payment if order_fulfilled?
```

Doesn't that read nice?

Answer (score 3):

Postfix style does not have the `else` section. It is useful when you only want to do something with one of the two cases divided by the condition and don't want to mess with the other case.

Answer (score 2):

It's the same as prefix but shorter. The only reason is to save vertical space in the text editor.